# does action_view.cache_template_loading really default to true in rails 2.3.x apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

according to the rails guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/2_3_release_notes.html (section 6.8), config.action_view.cache_template_loading defaults to true in production and test.

however, when i check the variable Rails.configuration.action_view.cache_template_loading, it gives back a nil value unless i explicitly set it to true.

are the rails guides wrong? if so, i'd like to submit a correction. but wanted to make sure i'm not missing something.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`ActionView::Resolver.caching?` is what you want to check, not `Rails.configuration.action_view.cache_template_loading`.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/railties/test/application/configuration_test.rb#L795-L831 are the tests for the functionality.